# Как сделать закрытие Navigation View не полностью?

Tags: android

Я использую `Navigation View`. Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии, `Navigation View` закрывался неполностью, а оставалась видна его часть (примерно 20%). Пробовал делать отступы в самом `Navigation View`, но не помогло. Заранее благодарен.